# SVGs not scaling properly in IE - has extra space

Tags: html, css, svg

I decided to switch to svg symbols for one of my projects - but need them to be **responsive**. The main idea is not to have multiple http requests, so I was thinking of merging all SVGs into one SVG, define symbols and use them as follows:

```
<svg style="display:none;">
<defs>
<symbol id="mys">
    <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#3F77BC" d="M222.1,77.7h-10.3c0.1-0.8,0.2-1.4,0.2-2.3
        c0-8.5-6.9-15.4-15.4-15.4c-8.5,0-15.4,6.9-15.4,15.4c0,0.9,0.1,1.5,0.2,2.3h-9.3v4h-24.9v-5.2H89.4c0-0.3,0-0.6,0-0.9
        C89.4,67.1,82.5,60,74,60s-15.4,6.9-15.4,15.4c0,0.3,0,0.6,0,0.9h-6.2V60.7h4.3l5.3-5.3h22.8L74.3,44.9l-13.5-3.6l0.5-1.7
        l-16.5-4.4c-0.3,0.1-0.7,0.2-1,0.2l0,21.4h2v7.2c0,0-2,0.6-1.9,1.3c0.1,0.7,4.1,2.6,3.4,5.5c-0.6,2.9-1.6,4.8-4.4,4.5
        c-2.7-0.3-3.4-1.4-3.4-2.6c-0.1-1.2,0-3,0-3L38,67.9c0,0,2-0.5,2.6,1.1c0.6,1.5-0.2,2.7,0.6,3.5c0.8,0.8,4.1,1.4,4.1-1.1
        c0-2.5-0.5-2.4-2.1-3.6c-1.7-1.2-3.4-2.8-3.4-3.3c0-0.5-0.1-7.7-0.1-7.7h2.1l0-21.7c-1.4-0.7-2.5-2.1-2.5-3.8
        c0-2.3,1.9-4.2,4.2-4.2c2,0,3.6,1.4,4.1,3.2l15.3,4.1l0.4-1.6l55.8,15.1h28.1c0,0,0-23.5,0-26.2c0-2.7,2.1-2.6,2.1-2.6
        s32.5-0.5,35.1,0.5c2.7,1,3.3,3.7,3.3,3.7h-2l5,11.6c0,0,7.3,4.6,17.6,7.6c10.3,3,13.6,7.6,13.6,7.6l-1,17.6l1.3,2V77.7z
         M81.5,46.8l8.6,8.6h9.3l2.9-2.9L81.5,46.8z M175.5,25l-17.4-0.1v12.6h9.6l2.7,2.7h6.6L175.5,25z M183,23.7h-4c0,0,2,6.6,3,9.9
        s0.9,4.2,2.7,4.2c1.9,0,4.2,0,4.2,0L183,23.7z M74.2,63.8c6.8,0,12.3,5.5,12.3,12.3S81,88.4,74.2,88.4c-6.8,0-12.3-5.5-12.3-12.3
        S67.4,63.8,74.2,63.8z M196.6,63.8c6.8,0,12.3,5.5,12.3,12.3s-5.5,12.3-12.3,12.3s-12.3-5.5-12.3-12.3S189.8,63.8,196.6,63.8z"/>
</symbol>
</defs>
</svg>
<div style="position:relative;width:100%;background:blue;">
  <svg class="mys" viewBox="0 0 254 108" preserveAspectRatio="xMaxYMax meet" style="width:100%;">
    <use xlink:href="#mys"></use>
  <svg>
</div>
```

Here is a jsfiddle, check the different behaviour in IE (I checked 11 but read that 9 has multiple issues as well):
http://jsfiddle.net/ws472q71/

For the life of me I can't get this to work properly. The above code works correctly in Firefox and Chrome, but fails in IE. I read about IE issues, but I couldn't find anything that works.

What am I doing wrong?

Is there any other similar solution that can merge SVGs into one file and use them as responsive images?

Thanks!

Comment: Would [SVG Stacks](http://simurai.com/blog/2012/04/02/svg-stacks/) work for you?

Comment: Nope it's very pre-mature at this point. I can live without ie8 support, but not without Android support. Thanks for pointing it out though.

Comment: [Look at this JS solution using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72216071/19074969)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

As you have discovered, IE has a bug where it doesn't scale the SVG properly if you don't provide both the width and height.

To get it working in IE, you can use a trick discovered (?) by Nicolas Gallagher.

http://nicolasgallagher.com/canvas-fix-svg-scaling-in-internet-explorer/

The trick uses a `<canvas>` element. IE *does* properly scale canvas elements. So if you place one in the `<div>` with the SVG, the SVG will end up the correct size.  You just need to give the canvas the same aspect ratio as your SVG.

```
<div style="position:relative;width:100%;background:blue;">
  <canvas width="254" height="108"></canvas>
  <svg class="mys" viewBox="0 0 254 108" preserveAspectRatio="xMaxYMax meet">
    <use xlink:href="#mys"></use>
  </svg>
</div>
```

with CSS

```
canvas {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    visibility: hidden;
}

svg {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```css
canvas {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    visibility: hidden;
}

svg {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<svg style="display:none;">
<defs>
<symbol id="mys">
    <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#3F77BC" d="M222.1,77.7h-10.3c0.1-0.8,0.2-1.4,0.2-2.3
        c0-8.5-6.9-15.4-15.4-15.4c-8.5,0-15.4,6.9-15.4,15.4c0,0.9,0.1,1.5,0.2,2.3h-9.3v4h-24.9v-5.2H89.4c0-0.3,0-0.6,0-0.9
        C89.4,67.1,82.5,60,74,60s-15.4,6.9-15.4,15.4c0,0.3,0,0.6,0,0.9h-6.2V60.7h4.3l5.3-5.3h22.8L74.3,44.9l-13.5-3.6l0.5-1.7
        l-16.5-4.4c-0.3,0.1-0.7,0.2-1,0.2l0,21.4h2v7.2c0,0-2,0.6-1.9,1.3c0.1,0.7,4.1,2.6,3.4,5.5c-0.6,2.9-1.6,4.8-4.4,4.5
        c-2.7-0.3-3.4-1.4-3.4-2.6c-0.1-1.2,0-3,0-3L38,67.9c0,0,2-0.5,2.6,1.1c0.6,1.5-0.2,2.7,0.6,3.5c0.8,0.8,4.1,1.4,4.1-1.1
        c0-2.5-0.5-2.4-2.1-3.6c-1.7-1.2-3.4-2.8-3.4-3.3c0-0.5-0.1-7.7-0.1-7.7h2.1l0-21.7c-1.4-0.7-2.5-2.1-2.5-3.8
        c0-2.3,1.9-4.2,4.2-4.2c2,0,3.6,1.4,4.1,3.2l15.3,4.1l0.4-1.6l55.8,15.1h28.1c0,0,0-23.5,0-26.2c0-2.7,2.1-2.6,2.1-2.6
        s32.5-0.5,35.1,0.5c2.7,1,3.3,3.7,3.3,3.7h-2l5,11.6c0,0,7.3,4.6,17.6,7.6c10.3,3,13.6,7.6,13.6,7.6l-1,17.6l1.3,2V77.7z
         M81.5,46.8l8.6,8.6h9.3l2.9-2.9L81.5,46.8z M175.5,25l-17.4-0.1v12.6h9.6l2.7,2.7h6.6L175.5,25z M183,23.7h-4c0,0,2,6.6,3,9.9
        s0.9,4.2,2.7,4.2c1.9,0,4.2,0,4.2,0L183,23.7z M74.2,63.8c6.8,0,12.3,5.5,12.3,12.3S81,88.4,74.2,88.4c-6.8,0-12.3-5.5-12.3-12.3
        S67.4,63.8,74.2,63.8z M196.6,63.8c6.8,0,12.3,5.5,12.3,12.3s-5.5,12.3-12.3,12.3s-12.3-5.5-12.3-12.3S189.8,63.8,196.6,63.8z"/>
</symbol>
</defs>
</svg>
<div style="position:relative;width:100%;background:blue;">
  <canvas width="254" height="108"></canvas>
  <svg class="mys" viewBox="0 0 254 108" preserveAspectRatio="xMaxYMax meet">
    <use xlink:href="#mys"></use>
  </svg>
</div>
```

The trick works whether you are trying to get it to match a width or a height.

Comment: Wonderful answer. In the meantime I realized on my own that I could give the svg absolute positioning, but couldn't avoid having to use padding bottom for the parent relative element. This works a lot better! :) Thanks!

Comment: Are you setting the width and height of the canvas element to be the same as the SVG? Is there no way to do this without explicitly setting both the height and width? I would like to be able to swap in an SVG with a different aspect ratio without constantly recalculating the width and height.

Comment: For me it also worked by setting the width in the CSS to `1em` so I can scale the svg with the `font-size` property. Works good for icons :)

Comment: Instead of using a canvas element, I used a ::before element on the wrapping div with bottom padding set to the aspect ratio to achieve the same . Saves introducing a hacky canvas element. 
`::before{ content:""; display:block; width:100%; padding-bottom:42.51968%; visibility: hidden; }`

Answer (score 4):

On a side note to help anyone struggling to implement this fix or finding its not working with external svg files rather than in-page svg markup

You need to ensure that when editing your svg file in a text editor it is not missing **viewBox** or **preserveAspectRatio** attributes in the opening `<svg>` tag. If these are missing regardless of what fixes you apply the svg will still not scale in IE - even though it'll scale in other browsers without issue.

If these options are set you can define the width/height on the image element used to pull in the svg to 100% and use max-width or max-height to limit the scaling and it will perform as expected. Though - you could still get some alignment issues.

Answer (score 2):

Nicolas Gallagher's solution works great, however, I ran into some responsive issues as I decreased the viewport. I thought I would pass along the fix I used:

```html
 <div class="parent-div">
    <canvas width="3" height="1"></canvas>
    <svg class="mys" viewBox="0 0 254 108">
         <use xlink:href="#mys"></use>
    </svg>
 </div>
```

I updated the "parent-div" with max-width:100%;

```html
.parent-div{
     position: relative;
     display: inline-block;
     height: 550px;
     max-width: 100%;
}
```

This will not solve all your scaling issues. You will still have to use media queries to change the height as you go, but at least the svg doesn't blow out its container. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score -1):

This can be rewritten like so if you're working with `<img>`

HTML

```html
<div class="ie-svgHeight">
  <img src="path.svg" class="ie-svgHeight-img">
  <canvas class="ie-svgHeight-canvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

SCSS

```
.ie-svgHeight {
  position: relative;

  &-canvas {
    display: block;
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
  }
  &-img { height: 100%; }
}
```