# IE issue with svg viewBox without specific height

Tags: html, svg, viewbox

This is the code :

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 70 35" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" class="canvas">...</svg>
```

and this is the css :

```
.canvas {
width: 70px;
}
```

The problem is that the aspect ratio is not preserved in IE (11, 10), although it works in Chrome.

Any idea on how to solve this issue in IE ?

Comment: Question is now edited and corrected.

Comment: @RickHitchcock It slices the `svg` element which is not what I intend to do.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way for SVG symbols to be responsive cross-browser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30415980/is-there-a-way-for-svg-symbols-to-be-responsive-cross-browser)

Comment: What you trying to do?