# Why does my button look different i IE?

Tags: html, css, button, svg

I have tried to find a solution for my button to look correct in Internet Explorer browsers, but not succeeded. What can be the problem here? Here is the link to the site: [www.vivids.se](http://www.vivids.se). Looking forward to an solution! :)

Here is the html:

```
<div class="share-wrapper">
 <span class="share-button">Dela</span>
 <a class="social-media-button" id="facebook" href="#">Facebook</a>
 <a class="social-media-button" id="twitter" href="#">Twitter</a>
</div>
```

Here is the css:

```
.share-button,
.social-media-button {
 font-weight: 600;
 display: inline-block;
 border-radius: 5px;
}

.share-button {
  padding: 0px 6px;
  border: solid 2px;
  border-color: #00d9ef;
  color: #00d9ef;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.share-button::after {
 content: url('img/share.svg');
 width: 13px;
 display: inline-block;
}

.social-media-button {
 padding: 2px 6px;
 background-color: #00d9ef;
}

#facebook::before {
 content: url('img/facebook.svg');
}

#twitter::before {
 content: url('img/twitter.svg');
}

#facebook::before,
#twitter::before {
 width: 13px;
 display: inline-block;
 margin-right: 5px;
}
```

The button to the left is Safari (MacOS Sierra).
The button to right is Internet Explorer 11 (Windows 7).

[image: Button in Safari]
[image: Button in IE]

Comment: Check out this similar question. I think there is a good chance it is your problem.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30415980/is-there-a-way-for-svg-symbols-to-be-responsive-cross-browser

Comment: Thanks, I will check it out!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is a cache problem? I opened it in IE11 and it looks like you said it should be.

[image]

Comment: its the version problem of IE

Comment: Actually I have not enabled cache on the site yet. So it is something else.