# width/height of SVG image messed up by IE10

Tags: css, svg, internet-explorer-10

I have an SVG image with clickable SVG polygons on it and some hover image effects on top of that. works perfectly fine in every browser, except - of course - in IE. actually edge (12 + 13) and IE 11 are fine. Even IE10 (Metro) - but not IE10 Latest (as tested in Browserstack).

Since this has to be seen with the images I put up a working example here (well working apart from IE10):
[SVG clickable images](http://plein.ch/test_svg/test_svg.php)

so following that link you can see what it should look like (again, except IE10) and this is a screenshot from Browserstack of what it looks like in IE10 Latest:

[image]

So in this specific case, the black & white-image (background) - instead of having a 7.5% margin-left and 85% width like the rest of the svg stuff - is resized by the height, which seems to be 100%, thus resulting in incorrect layering of the SVGs.

i really don't know what's causing this - any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are only supplying a `width` for the `<svg>` element (ie. no height).  So it is probably IEs SVG scaling bug that is your problem.  See the following question for a workaround.

[SVGs not scaling properly in IE - has extra space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30415980/svgs-not-scaling-properly-in-ie-has-extra-space)