# Bad proportions in inline SVG in Internet Explorer and Edge

Tags: html, internet-explorer, svg, microsoft-edge

If you shrink view, IE and Edge badly calculate rect positions and dimensions and it looks like lines disappear...

Is it a bug or can I modify the SVG code somehow?

Full demo: https://codepen.io/illycz/pen/XVoxyx

Sample code:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 5060.6 1066.5">
  <rect x="4851.3" y="939.3" class="st107" width="52" height="69.4"/>
</svg>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Is it a bug `IE`. Look here please - [Caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#search=svg)

> IE9-11 desktop & mobile don't properly scale SVG files. Adding height,
>   width, viewBox, and CSS rules seem to be the best workaround.

- Unfortunately, if you add fixed `height`,`width` the image will not
  be adaptive
- If you add these values as percentages of `IE`, the image will be
  scaled incorrectly

  You can try the trick  Nicolas Gallagher  http://nicolasgallagher.com/canvas-fix-svg-scaling-in-internet-explorer/

  and read the post where @Paul LeBeau [implemented it in practice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30416241/7394871)

Comment: @alexandr-t Hm, i'm place it absolutely to the container which has percentage dimensions, so it's almost the same like your mentioned example.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div style="width:80%">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 5060.6 1066.5" style="width:100%;height:100%">
  <rect x="4851.3" y="939.3" class="st107" width="52" height="69.4"/>
</svg>
</div>
```